# -Cannot Link CSS page to HTML

Tags: css, xhtml-1.0-strict

I am creating a html template for a webpage in a free HTML-kit text editing program. Both my xhtml and css files are in the same directory. I can link pictures to xhtml template but my css page is not affecting any change.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

 <html xmln="http-"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

 <head>

        <meta content="teggxt/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content- Type"/>
        <title>Spaghetti &#38; Cruft: Geek Pizzeria</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />


</head>

<body>
        <div id="branding">

        <h1><img src="images/logo.gif" alt="Spaghetti and Cruft: Geek Pizzeria">

        <p id="address">
        Spagetti &#38; Cruft<br />
        742 Cederholm Ave.<br />
        Gotham, CA 00234<br />
        510-555-0987
        </p>

        </div>

        <div id="main-content">
                 <h2>The page title will go here.</h2>
                 <p>The page content will go here.</p>
        </div>

        <ul id="navigation">
                <li><a href="menu.html">Our Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="reviews.html">Raves and Reviews</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html">News and Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tagline">
                 <p>Pizza, pasta, and WiFi.</p>
                 <p>Enjoy a bite with your bytes.</p>
        </div>

        <p id="copyright">&#169; 2007 Spaghetti &#38; Cruft: Geek Pizzeria</p>
</body>

</html>
```

and the CSS code.

```
html { 
background-color: #ffffff;
background-image: url(images/background.gif) repeat-x;);
}

body {
width: 80%;
}
```

Is the HTML-kit having difficulty processing XHTML 1.0 Strict? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using html strict, you need to close all of your tags always. `html`, `body`, `div` and `h1` tags is not closed right now. You miss some closing in the end of css description in `meta` tag also.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmln="http-"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Spaghetti &#38; Cruft: Geek Pizzeria</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="branding">
<h1><img src="images/logo.gif" alt="Spaghetti and Cruft: Geek Pizzeria" /></h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And your css is also quite clumzy. No need to put background elements in html if you can all put in body description. And also width is probably for that `div`, not for all `body`.

```
body { background: #FFFFFF url(images/background.gif) repeat-x; }
div#branding { width: 80%; }
```

Comment: They are actually closed I just did not put the entire code in the question feeling it was unnecessary to show the rest. But I will now put the entire html code.

Comment: `background-color: #ffffff;
background-image: url(images/background.gif) repeat-x;);` is not correct (there is typo in the end of line). Use `background: #FFFFFF url(images/background.gif) repeat-x;` And `h1` tag is still not closed

Comment: @Issac code you have mentioned was rendering the styles.Check  the css files are in the right directory

Comment: @JudeArasu yes they are in the same folder called S&P.

Comment: @mrserge the revision of the background you have pointed out has solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing " after styles.css.

Comment: I did close the quotations but I am still not getting results.

Comment: Do you have styles.css in the right directory on your web server? What do you see in your browser when it tries to load it?

Comment: yes I do have have both in the same directory, A folder called S&P. The logo <img> tag works fine and the correct picture appears but the background is blank white.